# How to install mysql to php5 on xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, windows-server-2012-r2

I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect();

After searching online I learnt that mysql is not included in this new version.

I am using xampp with PHP versions: 5.5.33 on windows server 2012 R2. I used **phpinfo()** function to search for MySQL but I can only find MySQLi, MySQL and and PDO but nothing for MySQL.

I need help to activate MySQL.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's because mysql is already deprecated in PHP v5.5.x

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Use mysqli instead.